# Iterator with multiple lifetimes

Tags: rust

Consider the following method:

```rust
fn search<'a>(query: &str, text: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut matches = Vec::new();
    for line in text.lines() {
        if line.contains(query) {
            matches.push(line);
        }
    }
    matches
}
```

I want to refactor this to return a lazy iterator instead:

```rust
fn search<'a>(query: &str, text: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item=&'a str> {
    text.lines().filter(|&line| line.contains(query))
}
```

However, this does not compile because now the iterator needs to live not only as long as `text`, but `query` as well. Adding an explicit lifetime to `query` should do the trick:

```rust
fn search<'a>(query: &'a str, text: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item=&'a str> {
   text.lines().filter(|&line| line.contains(query))
}
```

Unfortunately, this still does not compile:

```
error[E0597]: `query` does not live long enough
  --> src\lib.rs:32:39
   |
29 | fn search<'a>(query: &'a str, text: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item=&'a str> {
   |           -- lifetime `'a` defined here         --------------------------- opaque type requires that `query` is borrowed for `'a`
...
32 |         .filter(|&line| line.contains(query))
   |                 -------               ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                 |
   |                 value captured here
...
35 | }
   | - `query` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Any clue of what's going on here?

Comment: There is extra `->` a typo I guess

Comment: @KamilCuk Oops, yes you're right. Fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closures capture variables by reference unless the variable is consumed (moved) from within the closure.

Here, your closure captures `query` by reference, which means it stores a reference to a reference. [`&'c &'b str` explicitly implements `Pattern<'a>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html#implementors), so the closure doesn't need ownership of `query`.

Now, the closure is capturing a reference to a local variable, and the function is trying to return ownership of that closure.

The fix is simple: add `move` to the closure, so that a copy of `query` is captured instead.

```
fn search<'a>(query: &'a str, text: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item=&'a str> {
   text.lines().filter(move |&line| line.contains(query))
}
```